# Chebyshev´s inequality best sense

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

In class of probability we proved the Chebyshev´s inequality, and I wonder about a question that I have (not a homework) and is: How can I describe a sense in which Chebyshev´s inequality is best possible, i.e, when in a example, I can have the equality in this Chebyshev´s inequality.

My trying:

First we have $\Omega$, $\mu$ the measure and $\sigma^2$ (all finites), then
$$\forall x > 0, P(|x-\mu| \geq z) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{z^2}$$

Given that $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma^2>0$ and $z>0$ arbitrary, now I´m trying to define a random variable $X$ such that $EX=\mu$, $Var \ X = \sigma^2$ and
$$ P(|x-\mu| \geq z) = \frac{\sigma^2}{z^2}$$

Then with this I want to define $X$ as a discrete random variable taking three distinct values.

However I´m stuck here trying to define this random variable with all this considerations.

Someone could help me to solve this question, please. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a variable that is equal to 0 with probability $1-2a$,$b$ with probability $a$,$-b$ with probability $a$. Then you will have equality in Chebyshev's inequality when $z=b$, since the relevant probability is $2a$ and $\sigma^2=2ab^2$.

In most realistic situations Chebyshev's inequality is far from tight, but it still cannot be improved without sharper assumptions.

By the way, the Wikipedia article has the same example.

Comment: the variable is defined as $X= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   if  & P(X)=1-2a
             \\ b &  if & P(X)=a \\
             \\ -b &  if  & P(X)=a \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$ ?

Comment: @Knight No, it is given by its PMF $p(0)=1-2a,p(b)=a,p(-b)=a$. This PMF can be realized as a random variable in various ways.

Comment: I didn't see yet the definition of probability masss function, let me see the meaning.

Comment: @Knight If you like you can say $\Omega=\{ \omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3 \},X(\omega_1)=-b,X(\omega_2)=0,X(\omega_3)=b,P(\{ \omega_1 \})=P(\{ \omega_3 \})=a,P(\{ \omega_2 \})=1-2a$.